# No service for type has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I am trying to implement ASP.NET Core middleware, and this is the whole code I have in my project:

```
public class HostMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        if (context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("hello"))
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Hello World: {++Count}");
        }
        else
        {
            await next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMiddleware<HostMiddleware>();

        app.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Bad request.");
        });
    }
```

However, when I run this server I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'WebApplication4.HostMiddleware' has been registered.

[image: developer exception page screenshot]

Why do I get this error? Why would my middleware need to register any services if I don't use dependency injection in my project?

**Update:**

For some reason, this error does not occur when I stop using `IMiddleware`, rename `InvokeAsync` to `Invoke` and implement my middleware in the following way:

```
public class WmsHostMiddleware 
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public int Count { get; set; }

    public WmsHostMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("hello"))
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Hello World: {++Count}");
        }
        else
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

The question is still open - why does this happen? What is the difference? Why do I need to register services when I use `IMiddleware`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Today, when you use the IMiddleware interface, you also have to add it to the dependency injection container as a service:

```
services.AddTransient<HostMiddleware>();
```

Comment: PS: I submitted a PR to make it so this isn't required https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/pull/988

Comment: Hmmm, your PR is merged about a year ago and this is still required in ASP.NET Core 2.2. Was it reverted?

Comment: Part of it was reverted. You need to add the middleware as a service as well. Disposal was a problem

Comment: @davidfowl what is prefered `services.AddSingleton` or `services.AddTransient` ?

Comment: For IMiddleware, it should be transient as the intent is that it's created and destroyed per request

Comment: AddSingleton also works in (tried in .net core 6 )

Answer (score 8):

Implementation of `UseMiddleware` extension method uses container to activate instances of middlewares which implement `IMiddleware`, if that's not the case it will try to create instance using `Activator.CreateInstance` and additional ctor params which you may pass in `UseMiddleware` method.

You can take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/Extensions/UseMiddlewareExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 0):

It's still required to be made in 2023 of ASP.NET `6.5.0` with .NET 7

This is very weird because sometimes I could run my app without exception and time by the time it sends exceptions on the app start

My solution was:

- Remove `RequestDelegate next` from ctor of the Middleware
- Add the IMiddleware interface (i.e `public class MyMiddleware : IMiddleware`)

```cs
public class MyMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public MyMiddleware(ILogger<MyMiddleware> logger)
    {
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        
    }
}
```

- Add in `Program.cs` `services.AddTransient<MyMiddleware>();`

```cs
services.AddSerilog(logger);
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
services.AddTransient<MyMiddleware>(); // this one
```

- Add in `Program.cs` `app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();` (I put it after the `app.UseAuthorization();`)

```cs
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<GlobalExceptionHandlingMiddleware>(); // this one

app.MapControllers();
```